# Hybrid authentication with AAD and DB Users

Tags: sql-server, authentication, azure-active-directory, hybrid

We use LDAP and our local SQL Server databases to authenticate our users, using Apache Shiro as the app is developed with Apache ISIS. Users in the SQL Server database are REST consumers, while LDAP contains only business users. Lastly, I was instructed to move my LDAP users to MS AAD.

Is there an architecture that allows me to keep both users? Business users will access the app through the MS OpenConnect portal. At the same time, other applications can continue using DB authentication to consume REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Actually, the essential of your questions is "how to enable multiple authentication manner s in web app". Since AAD authentication is claimed based, very different from LDAP, so you will need to change your code for sure to upgrade from LDAP to AAD.

Regarding multiple authentication, I don't know the platform you're using. Here is an sample for ASP.NET CORE for your reference:[ASP.NET Core: Supporting multiple Authorization](https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-supporting-multiple-authorization-6502eb79f934)